# Can I copy files from another app /data folder?

Tags: android

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");

        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
        os.writeBytes("mount -o remount rw /data");
        os.writeBytes("chmod 777 /data/data/com.a.aas/a.jpg");
        os.writeBytes("dd if=/data/data/com.a.aas/a.jpg of=mnt/sdcard/b.jpg");
```

I can't copy this. How can I be done ? I added write permission to ext.storage !

```
        os.writeBytes("cat /data/data/com.a.aas/a.jpg > mnt/sdcard/b.jpg");
```

also doesn't work .. But Terminal Emulator can done it. Help me please !

Answer (score 0):

Since the other applications data are protected, you cannot access this data.

The permission you refer to about ext.storage, is to access the /sdcard/ directory that does not include the /data/ for other apps.

If you want to share data between apps, you should use ContentProvider API http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

You can read more about Android app data security here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

> By default, files saved to the internal storage are private to your
>   application and other applications cannot access them (nor can the
>   user). When the user uninstalls your application, these files are
>   removed.

/data/ is not on the sdcard and therefore won't be affected by ext.storage permission flag in your metadata.

Comment: My Phone is rooted ! I can access them from adb and terminal emulator by above codes! But not by app .

Comment: I've editted my answer to provide a more detailed clarification to what I mean. It's standard Linux filesystem security, this to protect users from malicious applications

Comment: Don't be complicate on my permission tag. This is about for 
 os.writeBytes("dd if=/data/data/com.a.aas/a.jpg of=mnt/sdcard/b.jpg"); .. Thank you for answering !

Answer (score 0):

How about using

```
       p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c cp /data/data/com.a.aas/a.jpg /mnt/sdcard/b.jpg");
       p.waitFor();
```

with

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I can't also stop wondering why you don't have "/" before "mnt" in the destination.

Or you can get the externalstorage directory before copying something to it,

```
    String s=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c cp /data/data/com.a.aas/a.jpg "+ s +"/b.jpg");

    p.waitFor(); // it is good practice to wait
```

Comment: Do you really need to change the permisions and mount things? I did not have to before.

Comment: /mnt is miss typing only.And I have no cp in the bin folder. And I have to change the file permission to access the data in root directory. Thank you for answering.